# How to get the last nonmissing prior two consecutive missing in sas

Tags: sas

I am trying to select the last non-missing DAT value to ADT which if the SUBJID have two **consecutive missing** DAT, else the latest DAT will be set to the value of ADT.
Below code produce the data I **have**, and I want to have the ADT could be derived with the illustratioin of below rule (*either finally merged to this set HAVE or just create into a totally new set*):

for subjid 1001: 1997-05-01 for this subject, there is no consecutive missing (though  only single non-consecutive missing)

for subjid 1002: 1998-02-01, as this subject has missing **consecutively** at AVISIT of 2-5

for subjid 1003: 1999-03-08, as the first **consecutive missing** happened at AVISIT of 4, and at AVISIT=3, there is non-missing DAT.

Hope you can help me. Thanks.

```
data have;
infile datalines truncover;
input subjid avisit dat : yymmdd10.;
format dat yymmdd10.;
datalines;
1001 0 1997-01-01
1001 1 1997-02-01
1001 2
1001 3 1997-05-01
1002 0 1998-01-01
1002 1 1998-02-01
1002 2
1002 3
1002 4
1002 5
1002 6 1998-12-01
1003 0 1999-01-01
1003 1 1999-02-01
1003 2
1003 3 1999-03-08
1003 4
1003 5 
1003 6 1999-05-01
1003 7
1003 8
;
run;
```

Comment: Do the two missing values need to be made non-missing, or are you simply trying to create a dataset that has these values?

Comment: Actually no need to make the missing values to non-missing, just create a new dataset is fine. Thank you for your quick comment.

Answer (score 0):

The below will create a dataset that includes the last non-missing `dat` whenever the count of consecutively missing `dat` is greater than or equal to 2. Each time we encounter a missing `dat`, we increase the consecutive missing counter `nmiss` by 1.

We are always storing the last valid value of `dat` in the variables `last_nonmissing_dat` and `last_nonmissing_avisit` such that they always carry forward when a missing value is encountered. When two consecutive missing values occur, we output the results.

`nmiss` and `last_nonmissing` are reset whenever we move to a new `subjid`.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by subjid;
    retain last_nonmissing_dat
           last_nonmissing_avisit
    ;

    if(first.subjid) then call missing(nmiss, of last_nonmissing:);

    if(missing(dat)) then nmiss+1;
        else do;
            nmiss = 0;
            last_nonmissing_dat    = dat;
            last_nonmissing_avisit = avisit;
        end;

    if(nmiss GE 2) then output;

    format last_nonmissing_dat yymmdd10.;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stu. Actually, I realized one key point was missed: I want to the EARLIEST DAT prior to the first consecutive missing. Thanks to your logic, I can find such information by use of below code, and **if you could guide me on how to modify  the data step to achieve this that will be better**: ```proc sql;
select distinct subjid, min(last_nonmissing_dat) as adt format=yymmdd10.
from want
group by subjid;
Quit;```

Comment: The way you are currently doing it as a secondary step with SQL is probably the easiest way. This could all be done in a single data step, but it may greatly increase the complexity of it. A two-step method is a good balance between the two.